# transfer packages from one conda environment to another

Tags: unix, conda

I am new to Unix environment. I have a small problem, due to some problem which I don't really get I had to create an new Conda environment and now I wonder if I can transfer all the packages from my old environment to the new (or I need to install them again?)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 7):

If you want to duplicate an env (say `foo_env`) in a new env (`bar_env`) you can use

```
conda create --clone foo_env --name bar_env
```

If you already have a new env (`bar_env`), and want to install packages from an existing env (`foo_env`) you can use

```
conda env export --name foo_env > foo.yaml
conda env update --name bar_env --file foo.yaml
```

Note that the `conda env` commands don't prompt for changes, so make sure to check the `foo.yaml` to verify that you really do want all the packages installed. Be aware that it will replace any duplicate packages if it involves a version change.