# Create new Conda environment using only packages from other environment

Tags: python, conda

I am working on an HPC computer and I cannot install packages from the internet. The Conda environments they have are huge and not well constructed (e.g., two or more versions of pandas in the same Conda environment).

So, I would like to create my own environment from the directory of the packages they reside. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with `conda create --offline`. It will use whatever versions are available in the package cache to satisfy the specified requirements. The setup is not entirely clear, but you may need to be sure the package cache is listed in the `pkgs_dirs` configuration variable.

This can be checked with

```bash
conda config --show pkgs_dirs
```

See `conda config --describe pkgs_dirs`.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I run conda confg --show pkgs_dirs I got /resources/conda/minicinda3/pkgs and /home/myname/.conda/pkgs

Comment: I am reading some documentation the team of my HPC provided but to do this but I don't understand how to do this https://research-help.genomicsengland.co.uk/display/GERE/Personal+Conda+Environments

Comment: It sounds like you should talk to someone at your institution.

Comment: yeah, that is the most reasonable way but contact them is not as easy as I would like

Comment: From the `pkgs_dirs` it sounds like it is configured, so try creating an environment like `conda create -n foo --offline -c conda-forge -c bioconda samtools`. If that doesn't work, then add the result to the question body (edit).

Comment: That env does't exist. Documentation is not update.

Comment: Why not an answer you already posted. Can I do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285916/transfer-packages-from-one-conda-environment-to-another

Comment: @Monkiky that clones the whole environment. Using the `--offline` flag, you can define a new environment with only the subset you want. Or perhaps I don't fully get the situation.

Comment: yes, you are getting the situation. But I can modify the file can't I? What I guess I cannot do it in the future if I want one package from another env. I cannot only extra that one modifying the file or can I? If I use --offline, how I select for examples a pandas 1.3 I have seen in the env FAA, and then a sqlite 3.36 I have seen in the env. loo

Comment: @Monkiky please try making some example environments and document how they fail in your question. The idea behind `--offline` is that Conda uses a package cache, where *all* environments commonly store their packages. It doesn't matter if the packages are installed in different environments. However, the docs for your organization imply that you have proxy access to specific channels, so the premise of "no internet" sounds off.

Comment: "*That env does't exist*" - you don't have to have an existing environment - the offline packages are pooled in the package cache.